# "Class Magento\Catalog\ModelCategory\Attribute\Backend\LayoutUpdate doesnot exist" in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I am facing this issue when I trying to setup **Magento2.3.2 p2** in my local system.

Admin is working fine. But in frontend I am getting the below issue.

```
Exception:Class Magento\Catalog\ModelCategory\Attribute\Backend\LayoutUpdate doesnot exist
```

I searched the web, but didn't find the solution.

Comment: remove generate folder and  run following commands 
1) php bin/magento setup:upgrade
2) php bin/magento setup:di:compile
3) php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: No, it's not working. I am unable to run di:compile command in my local as it is taking a lot of time to complete.

Comment: try this php -d memory_limit=3G bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: After running the above command on local, still it is taking a lot of time to complete. It stuck in 57%.

Comment: delete generated folder and then try that commands

Comment: I did it but still it was stucked in 58%.

Comment: Interceptors generation... 4/7 [================>-----------]  57% 27 secs 283.0 MiB

Comment: have you add any new extension?

Answer (score 12):

if you were using Magento 2.3.4 and then downgraded to lower version, run the following:

```
DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'custom_layout_update_file';
```

Clear the cache.